# 70's Sci-Fi Comic Magazine (anthology) about an alien crash-landing his saucer

Tags: story-identification, comics, anthology-book

A wonderful illustrated B&W story about an alien crash-landing his saucer, rescued and nursed back to health by a boy and his farmer dad.  They name the kind, benevolent alien "Pi", after the mathematical concept.  Plot is fairly typical, Pi uses his alien tech and powers for good, eventually prejudiced townspeople want to lynch him, they hurt the dad? And Pi destroys the town.

That sounds awful, but I don't recall that Pi actually killed/hurt anybody, just blasted the town to save his adopted Earth family.

Anyway, it was a sweet, cool story from some comic magazine, I think this was about 1975-6?  Back when kids traded comic books and magazines back and forth like currency.

I can not remember the name of the anthology comic magazine (again, all B&W, as I recall), or name of the story, just the alien was your typical tall, skinny hairless dude named "Pi/Pie".

Answer (score 19):

This sounds very much like the story *Daddy and the Pie*, a B&W comic drawn by Alex Toth that first appeared in *Eerie #64* in 1975. "Pie" is the name given to a tall blue alien discovered by a boy and his father, because the first characters the alien was able to write resembled 3.14 - the first digits of pi.

[image: Frames from "Daddy and the Pie", showing Pie writing his name]

The family and the alien become firm friends, but towards the end of the story some bigoted members of the town beat up the father, not wanting "blue-skinned monkeys" settling in the town. To defend his friends the alien goes to punish the men, by blowing up their homes.

[image: Frames from "Daddy and the Pie, showing the finale]

A detailed write up is available from this [blog](https://whencomicbooksruled.blogspot.com/2011/03/alex-toth-and-pie.html).

> "Daddy and the Pie" hearkens back to those message stories EC used to
> run where they'd sucker you in with gloriously drawn gore and freaky
> octopus-like creatures then teach you some kind of life lesson, like
> in that one tale about the little mutant girl who was so
> misunderstood. "Daddy and the Pie" also has a distinct Ray Bradbury
> feel in its mix of small town nostalgia, the melancholy truth of just
> how crappy we humans can be to each other and science fiction.
>
> Ultimately, however, "Daddy and the Pie" also reminds me of that Kenny
> Rogers song, "The Coward of the County." Some people-- and blue giants
> from other worlds-- can only be pushed so far before they have to give
> up pacifism and counter aggression with mysterious glowing orbs that
> focus mental power to wreak retribution...  The Pie is fully benign
> but he, like the less evolved people who finally drive him to
> reaction, is capable of destructive acts. In some ways his sacrifice
> and victory in the town is the most human moment in the story.

Comment: That was it exactly!  Good call, and thank you.

Comment: Great! Can you click the checkmark next to the answer to "accept" it? Then other users will know that the question has been answered. Thanks.