# What's the Entertaining Comics story about a "little mutant girl who was so misunderstood"?

Tags: story-identification, comics

This 2011 [blog](https://whencomicbooksruled.blogspot.com/2011/03/alex-toth-and-pie.html) mentioned in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/282742) mentions an Entertaining Comics story about

"the little mutant girl who was so misunderstood"

What story is that?

Comment: I think the title is slightly wrong. The blog mentions EC Comics, but EC stands for Entertaining  Comics, not Eerie Comics.

Comment: @BjornEriksson - Thanks! Fixing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds a bit like the story "The loathsome" from "[Weird Science #20](https://eccomics.fandom.com/wiki/Weird_Science_Vol_1_20)

[image: cover of WeirdScience #20]

It is about a small mutant girl that looks frightening but really just want to be loved.

[image: The mutant girl from WeirdScience #20]

The ECComic fandom page summarize the story like this

> A doctor sends a deformed mutant child that was the product of her father's exposure to atomic radiation to be brought up in an orphanage. The women of the orphanage dislike her because she displays poor behavior. One day the younger nurse comments to the older one that the girl is behaving herself recently and the older nurse recalls that all children receive a birthday party at ten years old and the girl must figure she is going to get one. The young woman asks if she is going to give the child one and the older woman states that it would not be right to expect the other children to attend, so they will just skip it in the mutant girl's case. They discover that the girl was spying on them and when she returns to her room she smashes the mirror. She's punished, and that evening the younger nurse sees the girl on the grounds stuffing notes into tree hollows. She assumes that she must be up to no good and informs the older woman. The following evening they confront the child demanding the note and the girl flees from them. She climbs up a tree branch overhanging the orphanage's spiked wall and loses her grip. As the note slips from the hand of the dying impaled child, the older woman picks it up. It says "To whoever finds this note - I love you."

Comment: I bet this is it so hard. Have a check.